# Serialising a string which contains backslashes with Json.Net

Tags: c#, escaping, json.net

I am trying to serialise an object which contains a UNC-Windows path to a shared ressource.

My code:

```
     public class NetworkConnection
     {
        public String LocalName { get; private set; }
        public String RemotePath { get; private set; }
        public String ResourceType { get; private set; }

        private NetworkConnection()
        {
            LocalName = String.Empty;
            RemotePath = String.Empty;
            ResourceType = String.Empty;
        }

        public static List<NetworkConnection> getNetworkConnections()
        {
            try
            {
                List<NetworkConnection> networkConnections = new List<NetworkConnection>();
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_NetworkConnection");
                foreach (var item in searcher.Get())
                {
                    NetworkConnection con = new NetworkConnection();
                    con.LocalName = (string) (item.GetPropertyValue("LocalName") ?? String.Empty);

                    con.RemotePath = (string)(item.GetPropertyValue("RemotePath") ?? String.Empty);
                    Uri uri = new Uri(con.RemotePath);
                    con.RemotePath = uri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("file://", @"\");
                    con.RemotePath = con.RemotePath.Replace('/', '\\');
                    con.ResourceType = (string) (item.GetPropertyValue("ResourceType") ?? String.Empty);

                    networkConnections.Add(con);
                }
                return networkConnections;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return new List<NetworkConnection>();
            }
        }
    }

   class PC
    {
        public Software.Software Software { get; private set; }
        public Hardware.Hardware Hardware { get; private set; }
        public PC()
        {
            Software = new Software.Software();
            Hardware = new Hardware.Hardware();
        }
    }

    public class Hardware
        {
            public List<NetworkConnection> NetworkConnections { get; private set; } 
            public Hardware()
            {
                NetworkConnections = NetworkConnection.getNetworkConnections();
            }
        }

//Serialising
       PC pc = new PC();
       using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("deimama.txt"))
       {
           writer.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pc, Formatting.Indented));
       }
```

Output (shortened):

```
\\192.168.1.1\\speech
```

Wanted Output:

```
\\192.168.1.1\speech
```

PS: I tried different ways with string replacing as well

Comment: How are you serialising currently?

Comment: Are you aware that backslash is the escape character in JSON?  Whenever there is a backslash, the serializer will escape it by putting another backslash in front of it.  (See [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/).)  The extra backslashes will be removed when you deserialize.

Comment: thx for your answer, pls post it as answer so i can tick it as the correct answer